# Counting "perfect squares" in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am struggling to get this concept to work.

I have to use a list of integers as a parameter and count the number of perfect squares (1,4,9,etc) in the list and output that value. So for example, if I entered myfunction[1,5,9] the output would be 2.

So far I have only got one function to work:

```
myfunction list = map per list
    where per y = floor(sqrt (y) * sqrt (y))
```

Takes the square root of the element multiplied by the square root of the element. My mindset with the above is that I could set the above result equal to the original element. And if they are equal to each other, that would mean they are perfect squares. And then I would increment a value.

My issue is that my book doesn't give me any ideas for how to increment a variable or how to incorporate more than 1 function at a time. And as a result, I've been aimlessly working on this over the course of 3 days.

Thank you in advance for any help, advice, or resources!

Comment: Take a look at `filter` and `length`.

Comment: your `per` is already *incoporating more than 1 function* - you use `floor`, `sqr` and `*`;) (yeah it's really as easy)

Comment: In Haskell you can furthermore *not* increment a variable. Every variable in Haskell is *immutable*.

Comment: You can find in the Haskell Wiki some code for a proper [integer square root function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generic_number_type#squareRoot)  . Then you might have a predicate function such as:  `isPerfectSquare n  =  let r = intSquareRoot n  in  (n == r*r)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### fixing your version

first completed your version could look like this:

```hs
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per y = floor(sqrt y * sqrt y) == y
```

this would even type-check but it would not work (try it)

that's because there is a small little problem - let's make it obvious by giving some types:

```hs
myfunction :: [Int] -> Int
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per :: Int -> Bool
        per y = floor(sqrt y * sqrt y) == y
```

you get an error:

```
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
```

it is trying to say to you that it does not know how to use `sqrt` for an `Int` - an easy fix is using `fromIntegral` and let it convert the `Int` into something that can:

```hs
myfunction :: [Int] -> Int
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per :: Int -> Bool
        per y = floor(sqrt (fromIntegral y) * sqrt (fromIntegral y)) == y
```

this kind of works (wrong answer) but gives an warning - we could get rid of with

```hs
myfunction :: [Int] -> Int
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per :: Int -> Bool
        per y = floor(sqrt (fromIntegral y :: Double) * sqrt (fromIntegral y)) == y
```

were we tell Haskell what type to use for the conversion (the warning would tell you that you default to this anyway).

So there is the wrong answer still.

@jpmarinier already told why - the way you test/`sqr` is sadly not cutting it (at least as I thought you wanted) - here is a fix:

```hs
myfunction :: [Int] -> Int
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per :: Int -> Bool
        per y = let y' = (fromIntegral y :: Double) in sqrt y' ** 2 == y'
```

where we first convert `y` to a `Double` value `y'` and test this.

Another option is using a *integer-sqr* as @jpmarinier mentioned:

```hs
myfunction :: [Int] -> Int
myfunction list = length $ filter per list
    where 
        per :: Int -> Bool
        per y = squareRoot y * squareRoot y == y

        squareRoot :: Int -> Int
        squareRoot = floor . sqrt . (fromIntegral :: Int -> Double)
```

that should finally work.

### without `floor` and `sqr`:

ok this is maybe a bit to grok for you but here is how you can do this by sieving out the values.

Let's start by creating a (ascending) list of all perfect squares - I don't know which type you want those numbers to be so let's stay generic as well:

```hs
-- need later
import Data.List (sort)

perfectSquares :: Enum a => Num a => [a]
perfectSquares = [ n*n | n <- [1..] ]
```

no let's make a function counting elements from two lists - if the lists are sorted this can be done recursively by walking alongside the lists - I don't know if your input lists are always sorted so let's sort it before:

```hs
countOccurances :: (Enum a, Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
countOccurances from list =
    countAlong from $ sort list
    where
        countAlong [] _ = 0
        countAlong _ [] = 0
        countAlong allXs@(x:xs) allYs@(y:ys)
            | x < y = countAlong xs allYs
            | x > y = countAlong allXs ys
            | otherwise = 1 + countAlong allXs ys
```

having both we can combine them for the answer:

```hs
import Data.List (sort)

countPerfectSquares :: (Enum a, Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
countPerfectSquares = countOccurances perfectSquares

countOccurances :: (Enum a, Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
countOccurances from list =
    countAlong from $ sort list
    where
        countAlong [] _ = 0
        countAlong _ [] = 0
        countAlong allXs@(x:xs) allYs@(y:ys)
            | x < y = countAlong xs allYs
            | x > y = countAlong allXs ys
            | otherwise = 1 + countAlong allXs ys

perfectSquares :: Enum a => Num a => [a]
perfectSquares = [ n*n | n <- [1..] ]
```

Example:

```hs
> countPerfectSquares [1,5,9] :: Int
2
```

Comment: nice answer ! However if you want to get rid of floating-point arithmetic completely, the usual Newton iterative method for the square root can be modified into an integer-only square root algorithm. See on **MathOverflow** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599481/integer-square-root-algorithm), and  [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34236), with an excerpt from the book of professor Henri Cohen. There is also some [Haskell code](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generic_number_type#squareRoot).